# Как правильно подать Context в Listener?

Tags: java, android, activity, listener, context

Моя MainActivity реализует OnClickListener. onCLick работает так: при нажатии по заголовку любого элемента списка (Listener присваивается каждому заголовку в биндере таким образом: view.setOnClickListener(new MainActivity());) этот заголовок (TextView) заменяется на EditText.

Текст onClick:

```
public void onClick(View view) {     
     switch (view.getId()) {

        case R.id.profileName:       
            String text = (String) (((TextView) view).getText());
            LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) view.getParent();
            layout.removeAllViews();


            EditText enterName = new EditText(new MainActivity()); //ERROR HERE
            enterName.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
            enterName.setText(text);
            enterName.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP,45);
            layout.addView(enterName);
```

При создании EditText программа крашится.

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                          Process: com.bubbly.freewalkr.tricode, PID: 12673
                                                                          java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.Resources android.content.Context.getResources()' on a null object reference
                                                                              at android.content.ContextWrapper.getResources(ContextWrapper.java:85)
                                                                              at android.view.ContextThemeWrapper.getResources(ContextThemeWrapper.java:74)
                                                                              at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3589)
                                                                              at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3694)
                                                                              at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:651)
                                                                              at android.widget.EditText.<init>(EditText.java:67)
                                                                              at android.widget.EditText.<init>(EditText.java:63)
                                                                              at android.widget.EditText.<init>(EditText.java:59)
                                                                              at android.widget.EditText.<init>(EditText.java:55)
                                                                              at com.bubbly.freewalkr.tricode.MainActivity.onClick(MainActivity.java:55)
                                                                              at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4785)
                                                                              at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19858)
                                                                              at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:155)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5696)
                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1028)
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:823)
```

Судя по всему, проблема в неправильно поданном контексте. Я пробовал разные методы, но все испробованные выдавали одно и то же.

Как правильно подать контекст в таком случае??

Answer (score 1):

В связи с особенностями работы классов `Activity` и `Fragment` лучше всего считать, что они не имеют публичного конструктора. Ибо в вашем случае, например, вы так создали объект класса, непривязанный к системе. Оттого и падение.

В вашем случае проще всего получить `Context` из аргумента: `view.getContext()`

Comment: Уже пробовал - та же ошибка.

Comment: @Freewalkr, не могу представить ситуации такой, чтоб это не сработало. Добавьте подробностей в вопрос

Comment: @Freewalkr, вы полностью неправильно присваиваете слушатель нажатий. Вам надо просто `this` передавать, а не создавать непривязанную к системе активити

Comment: Попробуйте использовать так MainActivity.this.getActivityContext() вместо new MainActivity()

Comment: @IvanVovk Куда это вводить: в присваивании слушателя в биндере или при создании EditText?
В первом случае пишет MainActivity is not an enclosing class, а во втором - can't resolve method "getActivityContext()".
Что делать?)

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Тоже на этот счет думал, но при попытке передать MainActivity.this выдает MainActivity is not an enclosing class.

Answer (score 0):

Нашел решение. Вписал в layout-файл элемента списка 
`android:onClick="onClick"`
Теперь все работает как надо.